# SELECT (with ? and $variable) returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry, but I do not understand where is problem.

This works

```
$query_select_date = "SELECT * FROM 2013Currencies WHERE DateOfCurrencyRate = '2001-03-23'";
$sql_select_date = $db->prepare($query_select_date);
$sql_select_date->execute();
$data_select_date = $sql_select_date->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But this does not work (get empty array)

```
$query_select_date = "SELECT * FROM 2013Currencies WHERE DateOfCurrencyRate = ?";
$cdate = "'2001-03-23'";// or $cdate = "2001-03-23"; or $cdate = 2001-03-23; result is the same
$sql_select_date->execute($cdate);
$data_select_date = $sql_select_date->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I suppose there is some mistake, but can not understand where.

Comment: You do not need the apostrophe around 2001-03-23. One point of using prepared statements is that the execute take care about that.

Comment: [**Since no one posted this, you should consider reading it.**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: Yes, need array. I read some examples, but forgot to read php.net. Now all is clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an array into execute method:

```
$sql_select_date->execute(array($cdate));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have not bound the `?` placeholder to the variable `$cdate`. Insert this:

```
$sql_select_date->bindParam(1, $cdate);
```

before you execute the statement.

Edit: lavavrik's solution is actually shorter, so I'd recommend using that over explicitly calling `bind` as long as it's not necessary.

Comment: I suppose it depends on circumstance really. I find it's more readable using the bindParam approach

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the parameter to the ?

```
$sql_select_date->bindParam(1, $cdate);
```